# Decreasing browser window - button icons don't end up where they should

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

To put it simply, when decreasing the size of your browser window, for mobile device view, the top buttons get pushed to the left, underneath the clients name and finally ends up in a Menu subfolder. Not being a web designer, although I am trying hard to learn, what I would like to see is the Menu subfolder react a lot sooner, before the button end up under the clients name. Being a free template of which I am trying to redesign, I looked under style.css and responsive.css but I'm not sure what I should be looking for. Any help with this matter would be very much appreciated.

http://landonmusicgroup.com/victoria_update_test/index.html

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell more simple and clear what you want your site to behave like?

Comment: @BlackFire I thought my description of what I wanted to do was extremely clear. I appreciate you chiming in but not sure how clearer I can be with a description so simple. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest smaller icons in general with less padding on the left and ride sides. This will create smaller icons that are closer together. You would likely have to scale the browser to ensure that the icons all fit before the media queries break to a single menu button at 767px.

The more efficient option would be to adjust the icons size and the logo size depending on the media query. For example, you have a media query in that template from around 980px to 1300px. If possible, in your template adjust the logo sizing and icon sizing to make sure that within that range, everything fits.

If you like the bigger icons, that is okay, you just must make sure that the bigger sized icons and logo do not take effect until after the window is over 1300px. Anything between 980px and 1300px is going to require smaller icons, smaller logotype, or a new arrangement altogether to avoid the line break.

Media queries are used like so:

```
//This section affects anything bigger than 480px
    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
        body {
            //insert width and height
        }
    }

//This section affects anything bigger than 767px
    @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
        li {
            //insert width and height
        }
    }

//This section affects anything bigger than 980px
    @media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
        li {
            //insert width and height
        }
    }

//This section affects anything bigger than 1300px
    @media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
        li {
            //insert width and height
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I can see the above code within both style.css and responsive.css but not sure on how to make it work. As I previous mentioned, this is all very new to me :) Assuming I wanted the the logo and icons to remain the same size, you wrote "you just must make sure that the bigger sized icons and logo do not take effect until after the window is over 1300px". Which of the .css would I find this in and would I have to increase the px size, over 1300? I'm really at a loss. Thanks again!